# Appending to the URL of matching .contains() text value

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a Chrome extension for myself and can't get around this. I have a ton of users signing up daily that always have the same keyword "examplespamuser" in their full name.

I can underline and log all of the matching results to the console, but I would like to change the URL value of the matching users by appending something to the URL.

The bit of jQuery I'm using now to log the users and their URL-s:

```
    $(".profile-link:contains('examplespamuser')").css("text-decoration", "underline").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

The users are displayed with their full name which always contains "examplespamuser" and the part above works well. The users have a link that takes you to http://example.com/examplespamuser123/something however, I'd like to modify that URL for matching users only, so instead it would be http://example.com/examplespamuser123/something/else.

Note I'm quite new to jQuery and JS so I'm not even sure I'm on the right path here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post the `html` that is being generated. Is the `console.log` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to modify the `href` of `spamuser` link.

Assuming your actual `url` will be `http://example.com/examplespamuser123/something`

Just do something like this

let's say your new route `/something/else`

```js
var newRoute = "/something/else";

$(".profile-link:contains('examplespamuser')").css("text-decoration", "underline").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(url); //actual url
    $(this).attr('href', modifiedUrl(url));
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(url); //modified url
});

function modifiedUrl(url){
    var splitted = url.split("//")[1];
    var furtherSplitted = splitted.split("/").slice(0, -1); //removing last route `/something`
    var withUserName = furtherSplitted.join("/");
    return "http://" + withUserName + newRoute;
}
```

```css
a.profile-link{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="profile-link" href="http://example.com/examplespamuser123/something">
  examplespamuser123
</a>
```

Comment: This worked wonders! I was pulling my hair out over the second function I was writing.

Comment: Also, since my URL was different (/something had to become /something_else) I didn't need splitting at all and could just use: `return url + newRoute;` after changing the `newRoute` variable. Thanks again!